# file upload with multiple files not working properly

Tags: php, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

I have this weird problem with my code:

There are three input `file` tags. These are upload scenarios and their results:

1. All three files simultaneously - success
2. Only picture - Success
3. Only audio - Failure
4. Only video - Failure
5. One picture and one audio - picture succeeds, audio fails
6. One picture and one video - picture succeeds, video fails
7. One audio and one video - one of them succeeds

   ```
   <?php 
   session_start(); 
   if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
       header('Location: index.php');
   }
   if(isset($_POST["year"])){
       ini_set('display_errors',1);
       error_reporting(E_ALL);
       var_dump($_FILES);
       $year = $_POST["year"];
       $height = $_POST["height"];
       $weight = $_POST["weight"];
       $school = $_POST["school"];
       $class = $_POST["class"];
       $target_dir_img = "./pictures/";
       $target_dir_aud = "./audios/";
       $target_dir_vid = "./videos/";

       $uploadOk = 1;

       $target_files = array();

       $target_img = basename($_FILES['uploadedFiles']['name'][0]);
       var_dump($target_img);
       if(strcmp($target_img,'')){
           $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_img,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

           $newImageName = $target_dir_img . $_SESSION['username']."_".$_POST['year'].".". $imageFileType;

           if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
               echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
               $uploadOk = 0;
           }
           else {
               $target_files[] = $newImageName;
           }
       }

       // Allow certain file formats

       $target_aud = basename($_FILES['uploadedFiles']['name'][1]);
       var_dump($target_aud);
       if(strcmp($target_aud,'')) {

           $audioFileType = pathinfo($target_aud, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

           $newAudioName = $target_dir_aud . $_SESSION['username']."_".$_POST['year'].".". $audioFileType;

           if($audioFileType != "mp3") {
               echo "Sorry, only MP3 files are allowed.";
               $uploadOk = 0;
           }
           else {
               $target_files[] = $newAudioName;
           }
       }

       $target_vid = basename($_FILES['uploadedFiles']['name'][2]);
       var_dump($target_vid);
       if(strcmp($target_vid,'')){

           $videoFileType = pathinfo($target_vid, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

           $newVideoName = $target_dir_vid . $_SESSION['username']."_".$_POST['year'].".". $videoFileType;

           if($videoFileType != "mp4") {
               echo "Sorry, only MP4 files are allowed.";
               $uploadOk = 0;
           }
           else {
               $target_files[] = $newVideoName;
           }
       }

       var_dump($target_files);

       // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
       if ($uploadOk == 0) {
           echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
       // if everything is ok, try to upload file
       } else {
           for($i=0; $i<sizeof($target_files); $i++){
               if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFiles']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_files[$i])) {
                   echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedFiles']['name'][$i]). " has been uploaded.";
               } else {
                   echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ?>


   <h1>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>!</h1>

   <h2>Data</h2>
   <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <p><label>Select Year : </label>
       <select id="year" name="year">
           <?php 
               for($i=1901; $i<=2020; $i++){
                   echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
               }
           ?>
       </select></p>
       <p><label>Height : </label>
       <input type="text" id="height" name="height" placeholder="Height" /></p>
       <p><label>Weight : </label>
       <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" placeholder="Weight" /></p>
       <p><label>School : </label>
       <input type="text" id="school" name="school" placeholder="School" /></p>
       <p><label>Class : </label>
       <input type="text" id="class" name="class" placeholder="Class" /></p>
       <p><label>Choose picture : </label>
       <input type="file" id="picture" name="uploadedFiles[]" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" /></p>
       <p><label>Choose Audio : </label>
       <input type="file" id="audio" name="uploadedFiles[]" accept="audio/mp3" /></p>
       <p><label>Choose Video : </label>
       <input type="file" id="video" name="uploadedFiles[]" accept="video/mp4" /></p>

       <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></p>
   </form>
   ```

Any inputs on how it may be happening?

Comment: Its working for me.!!

Comment: I don't know why but I face all the scenarios mentioned above. If I upload all the files simultaneously then it doesn't cause any problem! :( It's weird!